# prevent cms layout update from overiding .xml file template

Tags: magento-enterprise, layout, theme

Hello i'm wondering if there is a way to prevent the cms layout update overide within cms pages from overriding the .xml setTemplate?

my code:

```
   <cms_index_noroute translate="label">
    <label>CMS No-Route Page</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <remove name="cms_page"/><!-- REMOVE CMS 404 CONTENT -->
        <block type="core/template" name="content_404" template="page/errors/404.phtml" />
    </reference>
</cms_index_noroute>
```

but this won't override the layout update thats already present in the CMS -> Pages.

is it even possible via xml?

Answer (score 2):

The layout update should not override what's in layout.xml. It is merged with it. This is actually a feature. If you don't want the layout update to affect your layout, just leave it empty.

From your layout file I see that you want to show a specific template in the content of the 404 page.
You can do that by removing the line `<block type="core/template" name="content_404" template="page/errors/404.phtml" />` from the layout file and adding `{{block type="core/template" template="page/errors/404.phtml"}}` to the content of the 404 page in the backend.